# Follow up: ReversibleList V2: a list that is "reversed" in O(1) time

Tags: python, performance

This is a follow up to [ReversibleList: a list that is "reversed" in O(1) time [1]](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/279375/239973). Thanks for the suggestions!

Any suggestions for improvements are welcome!

A `ReversibleList`, `a,` behaves like a normal list when `a.reversed == False`.
`a.reverse()` "reverses" the list in O(1) -- the list is not actually reversed. What's actually happening is that in subsequent accesses to the list (e.g. `a[1]` or `a[4:7]`), the key (i.e. index or slice) is recomputed as needed.

I implemented this in two ways:

1. Composition: ReversibleList has a list attribute called `underlying_list`
2. Inheritance: ReversibleList inherits from `list`

The difference is that whereas the Composition implementation modifies `self.underlying_list`, the Inheritance implementation is modified through calls to `super()`.

The Composition implementation is better than the Inheritance implementation for reasons stated in [@jano's answer to [1]](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/279412/239973). I include both implementations here for completeness and in case it's useful.

#### Implemented as Composition

```
'''
author: joseville
'''
class ReversibleList:
    def __init__(self, iterable, reversed=False):
        self.underlying_list = list(iterable)
        self.reversed = reversed

    def reverse(self):
        self.reversed = not self.reversed

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.underlying_list)
    
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if self.reversed:
            key = self._getReverseKey(key)
        if isinstance(key, slice):
            return type(self)(self.underlying_list[key], reversed=self.reversed)
        return self.underlying_list[key]
    
    def __setitem__(self, key, val):
        if self.reversed:
            key = self._getReverseKey(key)
        val_reversed = False
        if isinstance(val, type(self)):
            val_reversed = val.reversed
            val = val.underlying_list
        if self.reversed != val_reversed:
            val = reversed(val)
        self.underlying_list[key] = val
    
    def __delitem__(self, key):
        if self.reversed:
            key = self._getReverseKey(key)
        del self.underlying_list[key]
    
    def __reversed__(self):
        if self.reversed:
            return iter(self.underlying_list)
        return reversed(self.underlying_list)
    
    def __iter__(self):
        if self.reversed:
            return reversed(self.underlying_list)
        return iter(self.underlying_list)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return '[' + ', '.join(map(repr, self)) + ']'
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{type(self).__name__}({self.underlying_list}, reversed={self.reversed})'
    
    @classmethod
    def _invalidKeyTypeErrorMsg(cls, key):
        return f'list indices must be integers or slices, not {type(key).__name__}' # same error one gets when doing [0,1,2][1, 2]
    
    def _getReverseKey(self, key):
        if isinstance(key, slice):
            # PRECONDITION: key.step == 1
            N = len(self)
            i, j, _ = key.indices(len(self))
            assert i >= 0 and j >= 0, 'I assumed that slice.indices returns positive values for start and stop, but was wrong.'
            i = i or -N
            j = j or -N
            return slice(-j, -i)
        if not isinstance(key, int):
            raise TypeError(type(self)._invalidKeyTypeErrorMsg('key'))
        return -1-key
```

#### Implemented as Inheritance

```
'''
author: joseville
'''
class ReversibleList(list):
    def __init__(self, iterable, reversed=False):
        super().__init__(iterable)
        self.reversed = reversed
    
    def reverse(self):
        self.reversed = not self.reversed
    
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if self.reversed:
            key = self._getReverseKey(key)
        if isinstance(key, slice):
            return type(self)(super().__getitem__(key), reversed=self.reversed)
        return super().__getitem__(key)
    
    def __setitem__(self, key, val):
        if self.reversed:
            key = self._getReverseKey(key)
        val_reversed = False
        if isinstance(val, type(self)):
            val_reversed = val.reversed
            # val is a Reversible list, we want only the underlying list...
            # https://stackoverflow.com/q/73652247/13881506
            val = super(type(val), val).__getitem__(slice(None))
        if self.reversed != val_reversed:
            val = reversed(val)
        super().__setitem__(key, val)
    
    def __delitem__(self, key):
        if self.reversed:
            key = self._getReverseKey(key)
        super().__delitem__(key)
    
    def __reversed__(self):
        if self.reversed:
            return super().__iter__()
        return super().__reversed__()
    
    def __iter__(self):
        if self.reversed:
            return super().__reversed__()
        return super().__iter__()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return '[' + ', '.join(map(repr, self)) + ']'
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{type(self).__name__}({super().__repr__()}, reversed={self.reversed})'
    
    @classmethod
    def _invalidKeyTypeErrorMsg(cls, key):
        return f'list indices must be integers or slices, not {type(key).__name__}' # same error one gets when doing [0,1,2][1, 2]
    
    def _getReverseKey(self, key):
        if isinstance(key, slice):
            # PRECONDITION: key.step == 1
            N = len(self)
            i, j, _ = key.indices(len(self))
            assert i >= 0 and j >= 0, 'I assumed that slice.indices returns positive values for start and stop, but was wrong.'
            i = i or -N
            j = j or -N
            return slice(-j, -i)
        if not isinstance(key, int):
            raise TypeError(type(self)._invalidKeyTypeErrorMsg('key'))
        return -1-key
```

- One weird thing about the Inheritance implementation was the way I had to access the "underlying list":

```
            # val is a Reversible list, we want only the underlying list...
            # https://stackoverflow.com/q/73652247/13881506
            val = super(type(val), val).__getitem__(slice(None))
```

Both implementations pass all tests:

````
def assertEquals(actual, expected):
    assert actual == expected, f'{actual} != {expected}'

def tests():
    print('Running tests...')
    
    a = ReversibleList([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

    assertEquals(a[1], 1)
    
    assertEquals(str(a), '[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]')
    assertEquals(str(a[:]), '[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]')
    assertEquals(repr(a), 'ReversibleList([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], reversed=False)')
    
    assertEquals(str(a[2:5]), '[2, 3, 4]')
    assertEquals(repr(a[2:5]), 'ReversibleList([2, 3, 4], reversed=False)')
    
    a[:] = a
    assertEquals(str(a), '[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]')
    
    a[2:5] = a[2:5]
    assertEquals(str(a), '[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]')
    
    a[2:5] = [2, 3, 4]
    assertEquals(str(a), '[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]')
    
    a[2:5] = ReversibleList([2, 3, 4])
    assertEquals(str(a), '[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]')
    
    a[2:5] = ReversibleList([2, 3, 4], reversed=False)
    assertEquals(str(a), '[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]')
    
    a[2:5] = ReversibleList([4, 3, 2], reversed=True)
    assertEquals(str(a), '[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]')
    
    b = a[:]
    del b[2:5]
    assertEquals(str(b), '[0, 1, 5]')
    assertEquals(str(b[:]), '[0, 1, 5]')
    assertEquals(repr(b), 'ReversibleList([0, 1, 5], reversed=False)')

    
    assertEquals(list(reversed(a)), [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0])
    a.reverse()
    assertEquals(list(reversed(a)), [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
    
    
    assertEquals(a[1], 4)
    
    assertEquals(str(a), '[5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]')
    assertEquals(str(a[:]), '[5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]')
    assertEquals(repr(a), 'ReversibleList([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], reversed=True)')
    
    assertEquals(str(a[2:5]), '[3, 2, 1]')
    assertEquals(repr(a[2:5]), 'ReversibleList([1, 2, 3], reversed=True)')
    
    a[:] = a
    assertEquals(str(a), '[5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]')
    
    a[2:5] = a[2:5]
    assertEquals(str(a), '[5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]')
    
    a[2:5] = [3, 2, 1]
    assertEquals(str(a), '[5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]')
    
    a[2:5] = ReversibleList([3, 2, 1])
    assertEquals(str(a), '[5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]')
    
    a[2:5] = ReversibleList([3, 2, 1], reversed=False)
    assertEquals(str(a), '[5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]')
    
    a[2:5] = ReversibleList([1, 2, 3], reversed=True)
    assertEquals(str(a), '[5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]')
    
    del a[2:5]
    assertEquals(str(a), '[5, 4, 0]')
    assertEquals(str(a[:]), '[5, 4, 0]')
    assertEquals(repr(a), 'ReversibleList([0, 4, 5], reversed=True)')
    
    
    
    a = ReversibleList([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
    b = ReversibleList(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
    
    aa = a[:]
    aa[2:5] = b[0:2]
    assertEquals(str(aa), "[0, 1, 'a', 'b', 5]")
    assertEquals(repr(aa), "ReversibleList([0, 1, 'a', 'b', 5], reversed=False)")
    
    aa = a[:]
    bb = b[:]
    bb.reverse()
    aa[2:5] = bb[0:2]
    assertEquals(str(aa), "[0, 1, 'e', 'd', 5]")
    assertEquals(repr(aa), "ReversibleList([0, 1, 'e', 'd', 5], reversed=False)")
    
    aa = a[:]
    aa.reverse()
    aa[2:5] = b[0:2]
    assertEquals(str(aa), "[5, 4, 'a', 'b', 0]")
    assertEquals(repr(aa), "ReversibleList([0, 'b', 'a', 4, 5], reversed=True)")
    
    aa = a[:]
    bb = b[:]
    aa.reverse()
    bb.reverse()
    aa[2:5] = bb[0:2]
    assertEquals(str(aa), "[5, 4, 'e', 'd', 0]")
    assertEquals(repr(aa), "ReversibleList([0, 'd', 'e', 4, 5], reversed=True)")

    print('All tests passed!')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tests()
```
````

Comment: `val = super(type(self), val).__getitem__(slice(None))` is just wrong. The underlying list **is just `self`**. You could have just done `self[:]`, but you don't want to do that!

Comment: Thanks! It does feel wrong. In `__getitem__(self, key, val)` `self` and `val` may refer to different objects. `self` refers to a `ReversibleList` and `val` may refer to an object, a `list`, or a `ReversibleList` which may or may not be equal to `self`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are trying to say?